# Haskell Listing the first 10 numbers starting from 1 which are divisible by all the numbers from 2 to 15

Tags: haskell

--for number divisible by 15 we can get it easily

```
take 10 [x | x <- [1..] , x `mod` 15 == 0 ]
```

--but for all how do I use the all  option

```
take 10 [x | x <- [1..] , x `mod` [2..15] == 0 ]
take 10 [x | x <- [1..] , all x `mod` [2..15] == 0 ]
```

I want to understand how to use all in this particular case.

I have read Haskell documentation but I am new to this language coming from Python so I am unable to figure the logic.

Answer (score 0):

First you can have a function to check if a number is mod by all [2..15].

```hs
modByNumbers x ns = all (\n -> x `mod` n == 0) ns
```

Then you can use it like the `mod` function:

```hs
take 10 [x | x <- [1..] , x `modByNumbers` [2..15] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Decompose the problem.

- You already know how to take the first 10 elements of a list, so set that aside and forget about it. There are infinitely many numbers divisible by all of [2,15], **your remaining task is to list them all**.
- There are infinitely many natural numbers (unconstrained), and you already know how to list them all (`[1..]`), so **your remaining task is to transform that list into the "sub-list" who's elements are divisible by all of [2,15]**.
- You already know how to transform a list into the "sub-list" satisfying some constraint (`predicate :: X -> Bool`). You're using a list comprehension in your posted code, but I think the rest of this is going to be easier if you use `filter` instead. Either way, **your remaining task is to represent *"is divisible by all of [2,15]"* as a predicate.**.
- You already know how to check if a number `x` is divisible by another number `y`. Now for something new: you want to abstract that as a predicate on `x`, *and* you want to parameterize that predicate by `y`. I'm sure you could get this part on your own if asked:
  `divisibleBy :: Int -> (Int -> Bool)`
  `` divisibleBy y x = 0 == (x `mod` y) ``
  You already know how to represent [2,15] as `[2..15]`; we can turn that into *a list of predicates* using `fmap divisibleBy`. (Or `map`, worry about that difference tomorrow.) **Your remaining task is to turn a list of predicates into a predicate.**
- You have a couple of options, but you already found `all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`, so I'll suggest `all ($ x)`. ([note](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36-))

Once you've put all these pieces together into something that works, you'll probably be able to boil it back down into something that looks a little bit like what you first wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, using math, we know that the smallest number divible by all numbers less than `n` is the product of all of the prime numbers `x` less than `n` raised to the floor of the result of `logBase x n`.

A basic `isPrime` function:

```
isPrime n = length [ x | x <- [2..n], n `mod` x == 0] == 1
```

Using that to get all of the primes less than `15`:

```
p = [fromIntegral x :: Float | x <- [2..15], isPrime x]
-- [2.0,3.0,5.0,7.0,11.0,13.0]
```

Now we can get the exponents:

```
e = [fromIntegral (floor $ logBase x 15) :: Float | x <- p']
-- [3.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
```

If we zip these together.

```
z = zipWith (**) p e
-- [8.0,9.0,5.0,7.0,11.0,13.0]
```

And then find the product of these we get the smallest number divisible by all numbers between 2 and 15.

```
smallest = product z
-- 360360.0
```

And now to get the rest we just need to multiply that by the numbers from 1 to 15.

```
map round $ take 10 [smallest * x | x <- [1..15]]
-- [360360,720720,1081080,1441440,1801800,2162160,2522520,2882880,3243240,3603600]
```

This has the advantage of running substantially faster.

Comment: `smallest = foldr lcm 1 [2..15]`